# Присваивание значений одного ключа к другому в контейнере map

Tags: c++, алгоритм, ооп, map, контейнеры

`https://pastebin.com/UbQmXvsE`

У меня есть `map<string, set<CarModel>, less <>>> database`. Это словарь, содержащий в качестве ключа название компании, а в качестве значения - CarModel, это соответственно класс. Я хочу реализовать операцию Change oldCompanyName newCompanyName. Она изменяет название компании со старого на новое и удаляет из базы старое название компании. Но я хочу, чтобы к новому названию компании переносились ещё и её значения, то есть:

Ferrari : ModelA, ModelB

Change Ferrari Nissan

Nissan : ModelA, ModelB

Как можно реализовать передачу значений от одного ключа к другому?

Comment: Выбрать по старому ключу и запомнить данные, удалить запись, занести данные в map с новым ключем

Comment: @avp - Да, но я не понимаю, как конкретно это сделать. Я буду проходиться по массиву

`set<Database, less<>> tmp`

`for (const auto& k : database)`

`k.second = tmp?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно ничего там запоминать и удалять, достаточно (если я тебя правильно понял, тебе просто нужно поменять ключ на другой, и чтобы данные в нём моделей машин остались прежними) просто поменять ключ.
С с++ 17 это делается с помощью метода [extract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract).

Условно говоря, псевдокод будет примерно такой:

```
auto node = database.extract("Ferrari");
node.key() = "Nissan";
database.insert(move(node));
```

Comment: Хаха, действительно, работает. А можешь пожалуйста объяснить, что делает move?

Comment: @ShinyEagle77, если вкратце, `move` занулит старое значение переменной node, перенеся все её данные в параметр метода `insert`, таким образом, избавившись от лишнего копирования и превратив `node` во временный объект. Почитай статью по ссылке, этот весь раздел в с++ называется семантикой перемещения.
https://ravesli.com/urok-192-std-move/

Comment: Спасибо, отдельное и за ссылку на источник!